# How does the Keras ImageDataGenerator resize images?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

I am using trying to use the flow_from_directory method of the Keras ImageDataGenerator class. The method as an argument called target_size that states that it will resize the images to the given size. I am just trying to figure out exactly what it does to resize the images but I am not sure where to look to get further information on this.

The documentation for the class can be found here:
https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You mean the interpolating method?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to find the method used for this class.